# Windows Azure Application high volume of records insertions

Tags: windows, azure, azure-sql-database, multi-tenant

We are meant to be developing a Web based application based on Azure platform, though I’ve got some basic understanding but still have many questions

The application that we are to develop will have lot of database interaction and would need to insert a large volume of records every day.

What is the best way to interact with db here is via Queue (ie work role and then worker role reads queue and save data in db)or direct to SQL server?

And should it be a multi-tenant application?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with windows azure SQL database of a little while now and this is a blog post i wrote about inserting large amounts of data

http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/ingesting-massive-amounts-of-relational-data-with-windows-azure-sql-database-70-million-recordsday/

my recipe is as follows: to Insert/Update data I used the following dataflow

◾Split your data into reasonably sized DataTables 
◾Store the data tables as blobs in Windows Azure Blob Storage Service 
◾Use SqlBulkCopy to insert data is into write tables 
◾Once you have reached reasonable a amount of records in your write tables, merge the records into your read tables using reasonably sized batches. Depending on the complexity and indexes/triggers present on the read tables, batches should be of about 100000 to 500000. 
◾Before merging each batch, be sure to remove duplicates by keeping the most recent records only. 
◾Once a batch has been merged remove the data from the write table. Keeping this table reasonably small is quite important. 
◾Once your data has been merged, be sure to check up on your index fragmentation.

◾Rince &repeat

Comment: HI there, really like you details blog and might do a POC based on it and was wondering if there are any other way to do so?

Comment: So far, this is how I got the best outcome. If you find a better way I am quite interested in hearing about it. I'm also open to discussion so please ping me directly on twitter and I will be happy to bounce Ideas.